# What file system fomat should I choose in Windows 8.1 disk management for my partition to install ubuntu 14.04.3 amd64?

Tags: partitioning

I've only run ubuntu from my flash drive so far but I want to install ubuntu 14.04.3 desktop amd64 on a partition drive I created. I want to know what file system I should choose to format the partition: ext2 or ext3? I am using AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard version. The other available choices are NTFS and FAT32 which I'm pretty sure I should not use. Also I'd appreciate suggestions for the size of this volume. I set it up for 200GB but I only have a 500GB hard drive and I shrunk my Windows partition to about 200GB prior to mking the partition. I don't want to make either partition too large or too small. I intend to use the dual boot option until I am more comfortable with ubuntu. Any advice or suggestions woul be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Installation Media

After freeing up the space I would suggest **not** creating a partition. When you boot from the installation media and install Ubuntu it will create all the necessary partitions: /(root), swap...

- I would suggest you boot into windows **at least once** after changing the partition size and **before** installing Ubuntu. This way you can make sure the partition re-sizing worked without a glitch. I know of users that blame Ubuntu for not being able to access Windows but the problem arise from an incorrect partition re-sizing process.

Also use **ext3**, the newer standards let you use more space and have files of greater size. Even better, use **ext4** if possible as it is more recent and has more options. The installation media however will make that choice for you if you use it.

Comment: Thanks, Torrien. Install went off without a hitch. Now have dual boot on my laptop.

Comment: Remember to select it as the correct answer.

Comment: Since I'm a "newbie" I wasn't aware of this option when I commented- can I do this now?

Comment: Bellow the vote up or down there is a check mark to select the answer as correct. And welcome to the community.